# Merge duplicate cells - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-merge

The intended operation is to search column A for duplicate values (column is already sorted). Each duplicate value in A should be merged into 1 cell. Also, merge the same rows in B,C,D,E,F,G,H (take the top value if different, but safe to assume they are the same).

THANK YOU!

From this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2kpJ.jpg

To this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Pds.jpg

I'm doing that manually for each order that is created and it's a huge waste of time.

Comment: I think what you really want to do is delete duplicate rows?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75363363/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Data > Data cleanup > Remove duplicates**.

Alternatively, you can **Insert > New sheet** and put this formula in cell `A2` of the new sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      unique(Sheet1!A2:A), 
      Sheet1!A2:H, 
      column(Sheet1!A2:H), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: But then how can I merge automatically the cells? (like in the photos) I'm looking for something like that just for Google Sheets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653535/merge-duplicate-cells?newreg=e53476aac7b94ed1ad7dcbf6a56c665b

Comment: The way I read your question is that you want to remove duplicates, leaving only unique rows in the data. The formula in the answer does that. It is unclear why you are insisting on merging cells. Please edit your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.